# Счетчик css counter

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Нужно чтоб счетчик состоял из 3 чисел, например 001, 002, 003 при переходе на 10 элемент было 010

```
counter-increment: step;
content: '[ 00'counter(step)' ]';
```

Comment: google + "css decimal-leading-zero"

Comment: получилось, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Думаю ответов на этот вопрос множество, но позвольте, как вариант, предложить мой )
То, что первым пришло в голову:

```js
function addZeros( num, length ){
  return Array( length - String(num).length ).fill(0).join('') + String(num);
}

// А если всегда до трех знаков, то проще:
function addZerosThree( num ){
  return '000'.slice(0, 3 - String(num).length) + String(num);
}

console.log( addZeros(718, 5) );
console.log( addZerosThree(37) );
```